# Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer ''. This operation might require other privileges

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-services

i have used the impersonation process to get privilages to the remote computer with the username and password of administrator. But i'm still getting the above error.
My computer is not in any domain. It is in a workgroup. And the logonuser function from Advapi32.dll used to impersonate has domain as one of the parameter.

```
LogonUser(user, domain, password,
          LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
          ref tokenHandle);
```

I've passed the null value to the domain. Is this the problem or something else. Is there any way to have access to the services of remote computer in a workgroup.

Comment: You aren't showing us the actual *arguments* that you're passing to the functions. Are we just supposed to trust from the variable names that you got them all correct? For example, if you pass null for the domain, you must specify a user name in UPN format. Did you do that?

Comment: when i use the following code, it now works 
      LogonUser(logon, null, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, ref token)
the impersonation is success with the logonUser function but still Im getting the above error.
And I think UPN format should be used if i have to specify the domain if I am not wrong. But in my case i donot have any domain.